# How to map each distinct value of a column in one table with each distinct value of a column in another table in Hive

Tags: hive

I have two tables in Hive, Table1 and Table2. I want to get each distinct customerID in Table1 and map it to each distinct value in a column called category of Table2. However I am a bit lost on how to do this in hive. A better example of what I am trying to do is the following: Let's say Table1 contains 5 distinct customerID's and Table2 contains 3 distinct categories. I want my query result to look something like the following:

[image: ExampleofTable]

However Table1 and Table2 do not have any columns in common so I am a bit lost on how to perform a join on this two tables in hive. Is this task possible in hive? Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a `cross join` of distinct values from both tables.

```
select t1.customerid,t2.categories
from (select distinct customerid from tbl1) t1
cross join (select distinct categories from tbl2) t2
```